# Does $exp(itA) = \lim_n [\frac{n}{t} R(\frac{n}{t}; A)]^n$ hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

In contraction semigroups the following holds:

Let $T(.)$ be a $C_0$-contraction semigroup $T(.)$, with generator $A$. Then for all $t > 0$,
$$T(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} [\frac{n}{t} R(\frac{n}{t}; A)]^n$$
in the strong operator topology (as $n \to \infty$).

[Theorem 1.36 from Kantorovitz - Semigroups of Operators and Spectral Theory]
(where $R$ is the resolvent $R(\lambda,A) := (\lambda - A)^{-1}$

Now I wondered whether something analogue is true, if we consider an unbounded self-adjoint operator generating the strongly continuous one-parameter unitary group $U(t) := e^{itA}$.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking to complicated... As we have $(1 + it \frac{x}{n})^{-n} \to e^{-itx}$ in the reals this holds true for self-adjoint operator via the functional calculus.